# Generate a function definition from a JSDoc comment (or vice-versa)

Tags: javascript, sublimetext2, webstorm, jsdoc

Is it possible, preferably, in Sublime Text or Webstorm, to type in a JSDoc-style comment, like so:

```
/**
 * Repeat <tt>str</tt> several times.
 * @param {string} str The string to repeat.
 * @param {number} times How many times to repeat the string.
 * @returns {string}
 */
```

And generate a function definition like so:

```
function repeat (str, times) {
    return
}
```

?

A vice-versa operation is fine too, I'm just looking for a way to save on extra keystrokes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would appear that [`sublime-jsdocs`](https://github.com/spadgos/sublime-jsdocs) is just what you're looking for for ST2. Scroll down a bit and you'll even see animated GIFs demonstrating automatic documentation creation from function definitions. It can be installed via [Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control).

I don't use Webstorm, but a [quick Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=jsdoc+webstorm) would seem to indicate that JSDoc functionality is [already built-in](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/creating-jsdoc-comments.html), although it doesn't look as nifty as Sublime's, which has a bunch of config options, is more flexible, and doesn't require running a bloated IDE :)

Comment: Outstanding. Thanks! P.S. I knew that Webstorm can work with JSDoc, there's even a page on their documentation dedicated to it - Read it again now, and I simply overlooked this line: "Type the opening documentation comment and press Enter to generate the documentation comment stub." Sigh. Anyway, `sublime-jsdocs` totally outranks what Webstorm currently has to offer. Here, have my +1.

Answer (score 1):

`sublime-jsdocs` is what u need.
Use [this](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/spadgos/sublime-jsdocs) link to install it in sublime through Package Control